# Syntax error in mysql statement used in shell script

Tags: mysql, shell, ubuntu

I am currently working on a shell script.
I want to modify the contains of the column "balance" in "Student" table as `"balance=balance-$deduct"` in shell script.
I am executing following line in shell

```
mysql -h "$host" -u "$user" --password="$pass" --database="$db" -e "UPDATE student SET balance=balance-$deduct WHERE pid=$pid";
```

Here i specified the host, username and password properly and i have one numeric value stored in `$deduct`
but when i execute the script i am getting following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE pid=132054' at line 1
```

where I am wrong here?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need --database=

```
mysql -h "$host" --user="$user" --password="$pass" "$db" -e "UPDATE student SET balance=balance-$deduct WHERE pid=$pid";
```

You can also do `Use $db` in you query

Comment: Thanks alot. It helped me

Answer (score 0):

Just remove --database=

It should work.